# HintText of a TextField component in Material UI does not hide its value when start typing into the field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have recently started exploring Material UI and I have run into this strange behavior of a hintText in a TextField Component(the one from Material UI)

This is my code:

```
/* in my component ... */
/* ... */
render() {
   const actions = [
                <FlatButton
                    key="1"
                    label="Cancel"
                    primary
                    onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
                />,
                <FlatButton
                    key="2"
                    label="Submit"
                    primary
                    type="submit"
                    onTouchTap={this.handleSubmit}
                />
               ];
    return (
           <div>
                    <IconButton                                                 
                       tooltip="Add Asset" 
                       onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}>
                        <Add color={"#000"} />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Dialog
                        title="Add"
                        actions={actions}
                        modal
                        open={this.state.open}>
                        <form>
                            <TextField hintText="Type" 
                                value={this.state.name} 
                                onChange={this.handleName}/>
                        </form>
                    </Dialog>
            </div>
        );
}
```

So when I start typing in the textfield, the **hinttext** **remains**, resulting in unreadable text due to letters over another letters.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me. :)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqVme.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this is that you will have to update the variable `name` in the function `handleName` everytime the user updates the field. So the complete code is:

```
<TextField
  hintText="Type" 
  value={this.state.name} 
  onChange={this.handleName}
/>
```

and the function `handleName`:

```
handleName=(event)=>{
  this.setState({name:event.target.value});
}
```

It should work. If not, let me know in the comments below!

Answer (score 2):

Try using placholder="Type" rather than hintText="Type".

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is called placeholder. I searched for hint, too.

```
<TextField
    placeholder="hint"
/>
```